# Что быстрее foo += inc или foo = foo + inc ?

Tags: qt, c++, creator

Что быстрее и есть ли разница?

Comment: а результаты профилирования показали, что Вы уже уперлись в эту конструкцию?

Comment: Гораздо интереснее вопрос что быстре ++foo или foo++ если тип foo определен пользователем, а не встроенный.

Comment: @KoVadim: вот! о какой оптимизации может идти речь без профилирования?

Comment: может человеку sse нужно, где можно будет по 4/8 переменных одновременно увеличивать.

Comment: Лучше всего получить ассемблерный код, генерируемый конкретным компилятором на конкретной платформе для разных вариантов, и посмотреть, что там происходит.

Comment: KoVadim, стараемся подчищать везде. это не такая уж сложная замена, но если на ней можно сэкономить, то не вижу причин игнорировать эту возможность

Comment: mikillskegg
gcc 4.6.3
стоит ли привязываться к платформе? нет.

Comment: @blondinka_Galaya может больше кода покажете? а то там могут быть явные оптимизации. если foo - это std::string или аналоги, то такой код может очень сильно тормозить.

 - профайлер запускали? или на глаз
 - уверенны, что чистите то, что нужно?
 - код в студию.

Comment: Блондинка, тогда просто посмотри в выше указанный код и сама реши. Если будет непонятно, неси его сюда, постараемся разобрать совместными усилиями. И вообще, мне кажется, если там и будет разница, то копеечная.

Answer (score 10):

Для базовых типов разницы нет, так как компилятор сам может провести оптимизацию. Для пользвательских же типов, для которых перегружены операции +, = и +=, компилятор не может быть уверен, что семантика у выражений a = a + b и a += b совпадает, поэтому он не может провести оптимизацию. В первом случае будет вызван оператор суммирования, создан временный объект-результат, а затем будет вызван оператор присваивания. Во втором случае будет вызван оператор +=, который пользователь возможно реализовал более оптимальным образом, например не создавая временных объектов.

Comment: Это да, однако же **крайне** не рекомендуется делать так, чтобы эффект этих двух выражений и вправду отличался.

Answer (score 6):

В качестве позднего дополнения к другим ответам:

Начнём с того, что есть существенная разница, если `foo` -- что-то большее, нежели простая переменная. Хуже того, вычисление `foo` может иметь побочные эффекты. В этом случае сравнивать скорость вовсе некорректно, выражения имеют различную семантику.

Точно так же выражения имеют различную семантику, если `decltype(foo)` -- не базовый тип, и вы вызываете перегруженные операторы. Здесь вам, конечно, надо смотреть в их реализацию, как правильно заметили остальные отвечающие.

Для базовых же типов современные компиляторы (исключая, понятно, экзотические embedded-платформы) сгенерируют в обоих случаях один и тот же код.

---

Если вы в таких наноулучшениях ищете потенциал для оптимизации, вы идёте на мой взгляд неверным путём. Потенциальное улучшение производительности на 2 такта процессора путём приведения кода в нечитаемое состояние закроет вам возможности для настоящей оптимизации. Если алгоритм просто и ясно написан, вы сможете скорее увидеть его суть и заменить на, скажем, другой алгоритм, при этом расходы по времени могут упасть с `O(n^2)` до `O(log n)`. Также, в неясном алгоритме вам потребуется больше времени на отыскание подходящих структур данных (большинство проблем со скоростью именно от этого, как подсказывает мой опыт).

Comment: В дополнение к ответу (свой писать не хочу т.к. он явно не по теме) - сейчас ИМХО лучше при оптимизации воспользоваться профайлером и посмотреть что тормозит, а уже потом оптимизировать, а то бывает что есть некий алгоритм, который можно улучшить с  O(n^2) до O(log n), но по факту он используется 1 раз за три дня и от его оптимизации мало что поменяется, зато есть другой, который, допустим, можно ускорить всего-то в полтора раза, но зато он постоянно крутится, скажем, поток каких-нибудь данных с датчика обрабатывает

Comment: @aknew: согласен на все 100, предварительная оптимизация -- источник всех бед.

Comment: у нас не тормозит, но нам надо ЕЩЕ БЫСТРЕЕ

Comment: @blondinka_Galaya: тогда не выжимайте полтора такта процессора, а переделывайте алгоритм. И/или делайте апгрейд железу.

Answer (score 3):

Быстрее или нет, вам скажет компилятор, которым вы это соберете. А с точки зрения логики - используйте тот вариант, который Вам поможет вникнуть в этот код в следующий раз наиболее быстро. Оператор `+=` подразумевает, что выражение простое, поэтому в него вникнуть проще.

Comment: рефакторинг и понятный код для слабых. нас интересует быстродействие. для остального существуют комментарии.

Comment: интересное умозаключение :))

Comment: знаю, звучит, как умозаключение, сподвигающее к быдлокожеству. НО МЫ ПРАВДА НЕ ТАКИЕ

Comment: @blondinka_Galaya: Я могу понять, как нечитаемый код может в принципе быть быстрее. Но как код _без рефекторинга_ может быть хоть с какой-то стороны лучше -- увольте, ума не приложу.

Comment: все зависит от того, к чему прикладывать. впрочем, рефакторинг -- это не подорожник.

Comment: вспоминается старый анекдот - в исходниках непонятный алгоритм на 3 экрана и комментарий "описание см. в тетрадке у Чена"

Answer (score 2):

Разница есть

В первом случае у уже существующего объекта `foo` присваивается оператор присваивания, которому на вход подается объект `inc`.
Во втором случае в результате операции `foo + inc` сначала создается временный объект являющейся суммой `foo и inc`, затем этот временный объект присваивается `foo` и разрушается.

Comment: то есть принцип работы как и в питоне?

Comment: Это в теории, на практике компилятор скорее всего сам заменит foo = foo + inc на foo += inc  , но как верно заметил @mega, это уже вопрос реализации конкретного компилятора.

Comment: @blondinka_Galaya: в какой-то мере да, как в Питоне, если класс foo использует стратегию copy-semantic.

Comment: На самом деле вопрос нетривиален. Все зависит от того какие операторы и как перегружены и каких типов foo и inc. Для базовых типов, мне кажется, разницы не будет и компилятор скорее всего и то, и то оптимизирует одинаково. А вот для пользовательских классов... давайте конкретику, короче.

Comment: обычный double. рассчитываем дистанцию между двумя точками.

Comment: Тогда (обычный double) определенно foo += inc.

Писать меньше, а главное читается быстрее. Исполняется одинаково.